# flutter data table's "showCheckBoxColumn" option is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm developing a table at `Flatter`.

In order to process selection/unselection for each row of the table, I would like to develop a `Checkbox` for the header of the table and all rows.

Then, I found the `showCheckboxColumn` option in the `DataTable` widget and applied it with pleasure.

However, as shown in the picture below, the `Checkbox` was not applied at all, and I can't find the cause.

[image]

The `DataTable` widget I designed is written like the following code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 34, 24, 24),
      child: Scrollbar(
        trackVisibility: true,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Selected Delete',
              ),
              SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 19),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: DataTable(
                  showCheckboxColumn: true,
                  headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFFEEEEEE)),
                  rows: _getTableDatas(),
                  columns: _getTableHeaders(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Is there any part of this code that I'm wrong about or I'm wrong about the concept of `DataTable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the docs,](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataRow/onSelectChanged.html.), You need to add `showCheckboxColumn` property to make the row selectable. Try adding and do let me know.

Comment: OMG.... your answer is perfect! For each rows I added ```onSelectChanged``` option like this
```DataRow(
          cells: cellList,
          onSelectChanged: (bool? selected) {
            selected == null ? print('selected is null') : print('select is $selected');
          },
        ),```
Then, a checkbox was appeared! Thank you so much

Comment: Always a pleasure, helping others :)

Comment: @SahilHariyani proper answer please with code